# birth-death process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, birth-death-process

This is from notes
[image]

I don't understand why $e^{-h(\lambda _i+\mu _i)}=1$?

and then the note shows that: 
[image]

But isn't $o(h)$ the probility of combinations such as 2 births and 1 death, 3 births and 2 deaths, etc, so $|X(t+h)-X(t)|$ is still 1, why the note says it is $P|X(t+h)-X(t)|>1$

Comment: Why do you think that exponential expression equals zero? It *tends* to zone as $\;h\downarrow0$ , though, **if** $\;\lambda_i+\mu_i\;$ is bounded.

Comment: if $h \to 0$ then $e^{h(\lambda+\mu)} \to 1$.

Comment: @EmilioNovati But I can also say if $h \to 0$, then $\lambda h\to 0$ too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't $1$, it is $1+o(h)$.

The $o(h)$ term is combined with other $o(h)$ terms so it looks like it disappears.

Comment: But isn't $o(h)$ the probility of combinations such as 2 births and 1 death, 3 births and 2 deaths, etc, so $|X(t+h)-X(t)|$ is still 1, why the note says it is $P|X(t+h)-X(t)|>1$